# Are there any tool for monitoring HTTP response?

Tags: http, tcp, network-tools

Are there any tool for monitoring HTTP responses? so open such tool up. give it URL. And it goes to it and brings you back not only body of http response but all http response.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fiddler2

http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler2/version.asp

Fiddler acts as an http proxy, it lets you examine outgoing requests and incoming responses (raw headers, data, everything).  It also lets you change requests, resend them and manipulate them directly.  It is invaluable.

[image]
<sub>(source: [fiddler2.com](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/images/tamper.png))</sub>

Comment: +1 This tool is great and has advantages over browser plugins.  For one, you can debug any application that is proxy aware.

Answer (score 10):

Use **[Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)**,if you're using FireFox.

[image]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](https://getfirebug.com/perch/resources/net.gif))</sub>

**Examine HTTP Headers**

[image]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](https://getfirebug.com/img/network/screenNet-headers.gif))</sub>

**XMLHttpRequest monitoring**

[image]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](https://getfirebug.com/img/network/screenNet-xhr.gif))</sub>

Also checkout the light version **[Firebug Light](https://web.archive.org/web/20190716221422/https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)** which works on all the browsers out of the box. no setup required. Firebug Lite does show Http Response headers and network monitoring but it's good enough to play around with the DOM.

Comment: +1 for the web developers friend, I thought Fiddler2 first but I use firebug far more frequently.

Answer (score 3):

Try REDbot:
  http://redbot.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a tool allowing to monitor HTTP requests / responses on client side, you should take a look at [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Answer (score 1):

[Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829)

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- Download "Live HTTP headers" or Firebug add-ons for Firefox
- Use wget with the -s option (if you're on Unix/Linux)
- Download something like Wireshark to see the whole TCP/IP traffic stream

Answer (score 1):

parros proxy is great for this : 
http://www.parosproxy.org/index.shtml

Answer (score 1):

http://www.httpdebugger.com/download.html

Or wireshark..

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but there's definitely a few tools available for this. The existing answers here give awesome recommendations if you just need to look at a request/response actively.

If you need to do automation HTTP response monitoring, you can use my tool: https://assertible.com. With this, you can set up requests and make 'assertions' on the response. If the response doesn't match what you expected, you can set up alerts to get notified.

[image: Assertible HTTP response viewer]

There are, of course, many other ways to approach this. For something more manual, I would recommend [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) or, for Firefox, Firebug as mentioned in another answer.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

well... I suppose that defines any browser, but if you want to analyze the response in code, cURL is one of the most used tools for networking, not just HTTP but other protocols as well. It will give you the headers as well as the body and allow authentication, etc., all from a command line or embedded elsewhere, as in a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

I love [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/suite/) but this is as much focused on intercepting and modifying HTTP requests as it is monitoring them.

Answer (score 0):

Not the specific tools you are looking for, but I highly recommend getting familiar with [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) and/or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) packet analyzers if you are into any sort of network programming. The latter has a "Follow TCP Stream" feature to look at the bytes flowing through TCP pipe.

Answer (score 0):

[GNU Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

`wget --save-headers URL`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I came across this thread and wanted to leave a link to [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/). Great way to simulate requests and examine responses...

Answer (score 0):

An open source tool [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) works great and is available on macOS, Linux, and Windows. It works great for API testing, but you can also use it as a simple HTTP client.